× Encountered error while trying to install package. ╰─> typed-ast
I have a django project which I cloned into my local but I am not being able to start backend coding because of the requirements not being installed. Everytime I try to install the requirements.txt, it gives me the following error.
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> typed-ast

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.

I have tried the following things.

Downgrading python version to 3.11.1
Downgrade the typed-ast to 1.4.2
Installed mypy latest version 1.10.0
Installed Desktop development with C++ and other packages.

I have windows 11. I cloned the project in other system which has windows 10, but it worked perfecty...I didnt have to downgrade anything. My error is as follows:
 Running setup.py install for typed-ast ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Running setup.py install for typed-ast did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [127 lines of output]
      running install
      C:\ALL_FILES\Projected\kvwsmb\myvenv\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
        warnings.warn(
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\typed_ast
      copying typed_ast\ast27.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\typed_ast
      copying typed_ast\ast3.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\typed_ast
      copying typed_ast\conversions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\typed_ast
      copying typed_ast\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\typed_ast
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\typed_ast\tests
      copying ast3\tests\test_basics.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\typed_ast\tests
      running build_ext
      building '_ast27' extension
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\ast27
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\ast27\Custom
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\ast27\Parser
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\ast27\Python
      "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.40.33807\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Iast27/Include -IC:\ALL_FILES\Project
ed\kvwsmb\myvenv\include "-IC:\Users\Aliza Paudel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\include" "-IC:\Users\Aliza Paudel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Include" "-IC:\Program 
Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.40.33807\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.40.33807\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\
Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\1
0\\include\10.0.22621.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program
 Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\cppwinrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" /Tcast27/Custom/typed_ast.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\ast27/Custom/typed_ast.obj
      typed_ast.c
      C:\Users\Aliza Paudel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o586qmu9\typed-ast_326fc7f310584db1b6b96f1c4187d291\ast27\Include\../Include/asdl.h(32): error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before '*'
      C:\Users\Aliza Paudel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o586qmu9\typed-ast_326fc7f310584db1b6b96f1c4187d291\ast27\Include\../Include/asdl.h(32): error C2081: 'PyArena': name in formal parameter list illegal
      C:\Users\Aliza Paudel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o586qmu9\typed-ast_326fc7f310584db1b6b96f1c4187d291\ast27\Include\../Include/asdl.h(32): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '*'
      C:\Users\Aliza Paudel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o586qmu9\typed-ast_326fc7f310584db1b6b96f1c4187d291\ast27\Include\../Include/asdl.h(32): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
      C:\Users\Aliza Paudel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o586qmu9\typed-ast_326fc7f310584db1b6b96f1c4187d291\ast27\Include\../Include/asdl.h(33): error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before '*'
      C:\Users\Aliza Paudel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o586qmu9\typed-ast_326fc7f310584db1b6b96f1c4187d291\ast27\Include\../Include/asdl.h(33): error C2081: 'PyArena': name in formal parameter list illegal
      C:\Users\Aliza Paudel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o586qmu9\typed-ast_326fc7f310584db1b6b96f1c4187d291\ast27\Include\../Include/asdl.h(33): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '*'
      C:\Users\Aliza Paudel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o586qmu9\typed-ast_326fc7f310584db1b6b96f1c4187d291\ast27\Include\../Include/asdl.h(33): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
      C:\Users\Aliza Paudel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o586qmu9\typed-ast_326fc7f310584db1b6b96f1c4187d291\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(398): error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before '*'
      C:\Users\Aliza Paudel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o586qmu9\typed-ast_326fc7f310584db1b6b96f1c4187d291\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(398): error C2081: 'PyArena': name in formal parameter list illegal
      C:\Users\Aliza Paudel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o586qmu9\typed-ast_326fc7f310584db1b6b96f1c4187d291\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(398): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '*'
      C:\Users\Aliza Paudel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o586qmu9\typed-ast_326fc7f310584db1b6b96f1c4187d291\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(398): error C2059: syntax error: ')'   
      C:\Users\Aliza Paudel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o586qmu9\typed-ast_326fc7f310584db1b6b96f1c4187d291\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(400): error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before '*'
      C:\Users\Aliza Paudel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o586qmu9\typed-ast_326fc7f310584db1b6b96f1c4187d291\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(400): error C2081: 'PyArena': name in formal parameter list illegal
      C:\Users\Aliza Paudel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o586qmu9\typed-ast_326fc7f310584db1b6b96f1c4187d291\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(400): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '*'
      C:\Users\Aliza Paudel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o586qmu9\typed-ast_326fc7f310584db1b6b96f1c4187d291\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(400): error C2059: syntax error: ')'   
      C:\Users\Aliza Paudel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o586qmu9\typed-ast_326fc7f310584db1b6b96f1c4187d291\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(402): error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before '*'
      C:\Users\Aliza Paudel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o586qmu9\typed-ast_326fc7f310584db1b6b96f1c4187d291\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(402): error C2081: 'PyArena': name in formal parameter list illegal
      C:\Users\Aliza Paudel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o586qmu9\typed-ast_326fc7f310584db1b6b96f1c4187d291\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(402): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '*'
      C:\Users\Aliza Paudel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o586qmu9\typed-ast_326fc7f310584db1b6b96f1c4187d291\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(402): error C2059: syntax error: ')'   
      C:\Users\Aliza Paudel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o586qmu9\typed-ast_326fc7f310584db1b6b96f1c4187d291\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(404): error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before '*'
      C:\Users\Aliza Paudel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o586qmu9\typed-ast_326fc7f310584db1b6b96f1c4187d291\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(404): error C2081: 'PyArena': name in formal parameter list illegal
      C:\Users\Aliza Paudel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o586qmu9\typed-ast_326fc7f310584db1b6b96f1c4187d291\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(404): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '*'
      C:\Users\Aliza Paudel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o586qmu9\typed-ast_326fc7f310584db1b6b96f1c4187d291\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(404): error C2059: syntax error: ')'   
      C:\Users\Aliza Paudel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o586qmu9\typed-ast_326fc7f310584db1b6b96f1c4187d291\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(406): error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before '*'
      C:\Users\Aliza Paudel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o586qmu9\typed-ast_326fc7f310584db1b6b96f1c4187d291\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(406): error C2081: 'PyArena': name in formal parameter list illegal
      C:\Users\Aliza Paudel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o586qmu9\typed-ast_326fc7f310584db1b6b96f1c4187d291\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(406): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '*'
      C:\Users\Aliza Paudel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o586qmu9\typed-ast_326fc7f310584db1b6b96f1c4187d291\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(406): error C2059: syntax error: ')'   
      C:\Users\Aliza Paudel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o586qmu9\typed-ast_326fc7f310584db1b6b96f1c4187d291\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(410): error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before '*'
      C:\Users\Aliza Paudel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o586qmu9\typed-ast_326fc7f310584db1b6b96f1c4187d291\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(409): error C2081: 'PyArena': name in formal parameter list illegal
      C:\Users\Aliza Paudel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o586qmu9\typed-ast_326fc7f310584db1b6b96f1c4187d291\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(410): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '*'
      C:\Users\Aliza Paudel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o586qmu9\typed-ast_326fc7f310584db1b6b96f1c4187d291\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(410): error C2059: syntax error: ')'   
      C:\Users\Aliza Paudel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o586qmu9\typed-ast_326fc7f310584db1b6b96f1c4187d291\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(413): error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before '*'
      C:\Users\Aliza Paudel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o586qmu9\typed-ast_326fc7f310584db1b6b96f1c4187d291\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(413): error C2081: 'PyArena': name in formal parameter list illegal
      C:\Users\Aliza Paudel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o586qmu9\typed-ast_326fc7f310584db1b6b96f1c4187d291\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(413): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '*'
      C:\Users\Aliza Paudel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o586qmu9\typed-ast_326fc7f310584db1b6b96f1c4187d291\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(413): error C2059: syntax error: ')'   
      C:\Users\Aliza Paudel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o586qmu9\typed-ast_326fc7f310584db1b6b96f1c4187d291\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(415): error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before '*'
      C:\Users\Aliza Paudel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o586qmu9\typed-ast_326fc7f310584db1b6b96f1c4187d291\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(415): error C2081: 'PyArena': name in formal parameter list illegal
      C:\Users\Aliza Paudel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o586qmu9\typed-ast_326fc7f310584db1b6b96f1c4187d291\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(415): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '*'
      C:\Users\Aliza Paudel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o586qmu9\typed-ast_326fc7f310584db1b6b96f1c4187d291\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(415): error C2059: syntax error: ')'   
      C:\Users\Aliza Paudel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o586qmu9\typed-ast_326fc7f310584db1b6b96f1c4187d291\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(417): error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before '*'
      C:\Users\Aliza Paudel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o586qmu9\typed-ast_326fc7f310584db1b6b96f1c4187d291\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(417): error C2081: 'PyArena': name in formal parameter list illegal
      C:\Users\Aliza Paudel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o586qmu9\typed-ast_326fc7f310584db1b6b96f1c4187d291\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(417): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '*'
      C:\Users\Aliza Paudel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o586qmu9\typed-ast_326fc7f310584db1b6b96f1c4187d291\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(417): error C2059: syntax error: ')'   
      C:\Users\Aliza Paudel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o586qmu9\typed-ast_326fc7f310584db1b6b96f1c4187d291\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(420): error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before '*'
      C:\Users\Aliza Paudel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o586qmu9\typed-ast_326fc7f310584db1b6b96f1c4187d291\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(420): error C2081: 'PyArena': name in formal parameter list illegal
      C:\Users\Aliza Paudel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o586qmu9\typed-ast_326fc7f310584db1b6b96f1c4187d291\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(420): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '*'
      C:\Users\Aliza Paudel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o586qmu9\typed-ast_326fc7f310584db1b6b96f1c4187d291\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(420): error C2059: syntax error: ')'   
      C:\Users\Aliza Paudel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o586qmu9\typed-ast_326fc7f310584db1b6b96f1c4187d291\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(423): error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before '*'
      C:\Users\Aliza Paudel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o586qmu9\typed-ast_326fc7f310584db1b6b96f1c4187d291\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(423): error C2081: 'PyArena': name in formal parameter list illegal
      C:\Users\Aliza Paudel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o586qmu9\typed-ast_326fc7f310584db1b6b96f1c4187d291\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(423): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '*'
      C:\Users\Aliza Paudel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o586qmu9\typed-ast_326fc7f310584db1b6b96f1c4187d291\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(423): error C2059: syntax error: ')'   
      C:\Users\Aliza Paudel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o586qmu9\typed-ast_326fc7f310584db1b6b96f1c4187d291\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(426): error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before '*'
      C:\Users\Aliza Paudel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o586qmu9\typed-ast_326fc7f310584db1b6b96f1c4187d291\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(425): error C2081: 'PyArena': name in formal parameter list illegal
      C:\Users\Aliza Paudel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o586qmu9\typed-ast_326fc7f310584db1b6b96f1c4187d291\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(426): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '*'
      C:\Users\Aliza Paudel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o586qmu9\typed-ast_326fc7f310584db1b6b96f1c4187d291\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(426): error C2059: syntax error: ')'   
      C:\Users\Aliza Paudel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o586qmu9\typed-ast_326fc7f310584db1b6b96f1c4187d291\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(429): error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before '*'
      C:\Users\Aliza Paudel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o586qmu9\typed-ast_326fc7f310584db1b6b96f1c4187d291\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(429): error C2081: 'PyArena': name in formal parameter list illegal
      C:\Users\Aliza Paudel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o586qmu9\typed-ast_326fc7f310584db1b6b96f1c4187d291\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(429): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '*'
      C:\Users\Aliza Paudel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o586qmu9\typed-ast_326fc7f310584db1b6b96f1c4187d291\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(429): error C2059: syntax error: ')'   
      C:\Users\Aliza Paudel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o586qmu9\typed-ast_326fc7f310584db1b6b96f1c4187d291\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(432): error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before '*'
      C:\Users\Aliza Paudel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o586qmu9\typed-ast_326fc7f310584db1b6b96f1c4187d291\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(432): error C2081: 'PyArena': name in formal parameter list illegal
      C:\Users\Aliza Paudel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o586qmu9\typed-ast_326fc7f310584db1b6b96f1c4187d291\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(432): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '*'
      C:\Users\Aliza Paudel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o586qmu9\typed-ast_326fc7f310584db1b6b96f1c4187d291\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(432): error C2059: syntax error: ')'   
      C:\Users\Aliza Paudel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o586qmu9\typed-ast_326fc7f310584db1b6b96f1c4187d291\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(435): error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before '*'
      C:\Users\Aliza Paudel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o586qmu9\typed-ast_326fc7f310584db1b6b96f1c4187d291\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(435): error C2081: 'PyArena': name in formal parameter list illegal
      C:\Users\Aliza Paudel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o586qmu9\typed-ast_326fc7f310584db1b6b96f1c4187d291\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(435): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '*'
      C:\Users\Aliza Paudel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o586qmu9\typed-ast_326fc7f310584db1b6b96f1c4187d291\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(435): error C2059: syntax error: ')'   
      C:\Users\Aliza Paudel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o586qmu9\typed-ast_326fc7f310584db1b6b96f1c4187d291\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(438): error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before '*'
      C:\Users\Aliza Paudel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o586qmu9\typed-ast_326fc7f310584db1b6b96f1c4187d291\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(438): error C2081: 'PyArena': name in formal parameter list illegal
      C:\Users\Aliza Paudel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o586qmu9\typed-ast_326fc7f310584db1b6b96f1c4187d291\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(438): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '*'
      C:\Users\Aliza Paudel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o586qmu9\typed-ast_326fc7f310584db1b6b96f1c4187d291\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(438): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
      C:\Users\Aliza Paudel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o586qmu9\typed-ast_326fc7f310584db1b6b96f1c4187d291\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(441): error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before '*'
      C:\Users\Aliza Paudel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o586qmu9\typed-ast_326fc7f310584db1b6b96f1c4187d291\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(440): error C2081: 'PyArena': name in formal parameter list illegal
      C:\Users\Aliza Paudel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o586qmu9\typed-ast_326fc7f310584db1b6b96f1c4187d291\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(441): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '*'
      C:\Users\Aliza Paudel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o586qmu9\typed-ast_326fc7f310584db1b6b96f1c4187d291\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(441): error C2059: syntax error: ')'   
      C:\Users\Aliza Paudel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o586qmu9\typed-ast_326fc7f310584db1b6b96f1c4187d291\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(444): error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before '*'
      C:\Users\Aliza Paudel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o586qmu9\typed-ast_326fc7f310584db1b6b96f1c4187d291\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(444): error C2081: 'PyArena': name in formal parameter list illegal
      C:\Users\Aliza Paudel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o586qmu9\typed-ast_326fc7f310584db1b6b96f1c4187d291\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(444): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '*'
      C:\Users\Aliza Paudel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o586qmu9\typed-ast_326fc7f310584db1b6b96f1c4187d291\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(444): error C2059: syntax error: ')'   
      C:\Users\Aliza Paudel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o586qmu9\typed-ast_326fc7f310584db1b6b96f1c4187d291\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(447): error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before '*'
      C:\Users\Aliza Paudel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o586qmu9\typed-ast_326fc7f310584db1b6b96f1c4187d291\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(446): error C2081: 'PyArena': name in formal parameter list illegal
      C:\Users\Aliza Paudel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o586qmu9\typed-ast_326fc7f310584db1b6b96f1c4187d291\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(447): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '*'
      C:\Users\Aliza Paudel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o586qmu9\typed-ast_326fc7f310584db1b6b96f1c4187d291\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(447): error C2059: syntax error: ')'   
      C:\Users\Aliza Paudel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o586qmu9\typed-ast_326fc7f310584db1b6b96f1c4187d291\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(449): error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before '*'
      C:\Users\Aliza Paudel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o586qmu9\typed-ast_326fc7f310584db1b6b96f1c4187d291\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(449): error C2081: 'PyArena': name in formal parameter list illegal
      C:\Users\Aliza Paudel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o586qmu9\typed-ast_326fc7f310584db1b6b96f1c4187d291\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(449): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '*'
      C:\Users\Aliza Paudel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o586qmu9\typed-ast_326fc7f310584db1b6b96f1c4187d291\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(449): error C2059: syntax error: ')'   
      C:\Users\Aliza Paudel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o586qmu9\typed-ast_326fc7f310584db1b6b96f1c4187d291\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(451): error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before '*'
      C:\Users\Aliza Paudel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o586qmu9\typed-ast_326fc7f310584db1b6b96f1c4187d291\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(451): error C2081: 'PyArena': name in formal parameter list illegal
      C:\Users\Aliza Paudel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o586qmu9\typed-ast_326fc7f310584db1b6b96f1c4187d291\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(451): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '*'
      C:\Users\Aliza Paudel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o586qmu9\typed-ast_326fc7f310584db1b6b96f1c4187d291\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(451): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
      C:\Users\Aliza Paudel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o586qmu9\typed-ast_326fc7f310584db1b6b96f1c4187d291\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(454): error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before '*'
      C:\Users\Aliza Paudel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o586qmu9\typed-ast_326fc7f310584db1b6b96f1c4187d291\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(454): error C2081: 'PyArena': name in formal parameter list illegal
      C:\Users\Aliza Paudel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o586qmu9\typed-ast_326fc7f310584db1b6b96f1c4187d291\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(454): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '*'
      C:\Users\Aliza Paudel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o586qmu9\typed-ast_326fc7f310584db1b6b96f1c4187d291\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(454): error C2059: syntax error: ')'   
      C:\Users\Aliza Paudel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o586qmu9\typed-ast_326fc7f310584db1b6b96f1c4187d291\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(457): error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before '*'
      C:\Users\Aliza Paudel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o586qmu9\typed-ast_326fc7f310584db1b6b96f1c4187d291\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(457): error C2081: 'PyArena': name in formal parameter list illegal
      C:\Users\Aliza Paudel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o586qmu9\typed-ast_326fc7f310584db1b6b96f1c4187d291\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(457): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '*'
      C:\Users\Aliza Paudel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o586qmu9\typed-ast_326fc7f310584db1b6b96f1c4187d291\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(457): error C2059: syntax error: ')'   
      C:\Users\Aliza Paudel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o586qmu9\typed-ast_326fc7f310584db1b6b96f1c4187d291\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(459): error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before '*'
      C:\Users\Aliza Paudel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o586qmu9\typed-ast_326fc7f310584db1b6b96f1c4187d291\ast27\Custom\../Include/Python-ast.h(459): fatal error C1003: error count exceeds 100; stopping compilation
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.40.33807\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> typed-ast

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.

My requirements.txt file
pytz==2021.1  # https://github.com/stub42/pytz
python-slugify==4.0.1  # https://github.com/un33k/python-slugify
argon2-cffi==20.1.0  # https://github.com/hynek/argon2_cffi
redis==3.5.3  # https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py
hiredis==1.1.0  # https://github.com/redis/hiredis-py
typed-ast==1.4.2

tablib
# Django
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
django==3.1.7  # pyup: < 3.2  # https://www.djangoproject.com/
django-environ==0.4.5  # https://github.com/joke2k/django-environ
django-model-utils==4.1.1  # https://github.com/jazzband/django-model-utils
django-allauth==0.44.0  # https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth
django-crispy-forms==1.11.1  # https://github.com/django-crispy-forms/django-crispy-forms
django-redis==4.12.1  # https://github.com/jazzband/django-redis
django-cors-headers 
django-rest-passwordreset
pillow
gunicorn
Collectfast
dj-database-url
django-autoslug
django-rest-knox
django-import-export
Werkzeug==1.0.1 # https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug
ipdb==0.13.5  # https://github.com/gotcha/ipdb
# https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2

# Testing
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
mypy==0.812  # https://github.com/python/mypy
django-stubs==1.7.0  # https://github.com/typeddjango/django-stubs
pytest==6.2.2  # https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest
pytest-sugar==0.9.4  # https://github.com/Frozenball/pytest-sugar

# Documentation
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
sphinx==3.5.1  # https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx
sphinx-autobuild==2020.9.1 # https://github.com/GaretJax/sphinx-autobuild

# Code quality
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
flake8==3.8.4  # https://github.com/PyCQA/flake8
flake8-isort==4.0.0  # https://github.com/gforcada/flake8-isort
coverage==5.5  # https://github.com/nedbat/coveragepy
black==20.8b1  # https://github.com/ambv/black
pylint-django==2.4.2  # https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint-django
pre-commit==2.10.1  # https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit

# Django
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
factory-boy==3.2.0  # https://github.com/FactoryBoy/factory_boy

django-debug-toolbar==3.2  # https://github.com/jazzband/django-debug-toolbar
django-extensions==3.1.1  # https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions
django-coverage-plugin==1.8.0  # https://github.com/nedbat/django_coverage_plugin
pytest-django==4.1.0  # https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-django
whitenoise
djangorestframework
django-filter
django-tables2
drf-yasg
django-filter



 I cloned the project in other system which has windows 10 - check the python and typed-ast version on the other system. typed-ast 1.4.2 has whl files up to python 3.9, so I would try to downgrade python to that version

The error is related to the C compiler not being able to compile the typed_ast.c
Try :
    pip install --upgrade setuptools

Another might be the visual c++ error
check for Install Visual C++ Build Tools:
If  issue persisite try using conda for python lower versions 3.8 below between 2.7 as the package supports this.
